# добавить информацию в документ ES+python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Есть 2 вопроса по elasticsearch

1. Столкнулся со сложностью при изменении документа в elasticsearch.

Структура документа:

```
{ service:{
            name: name,
            date: [{time:time, log: log}]
          }
}
```

Нужно дописать в объект "date" ещё один элемент массива.
Делал так:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_index/_doc/_id/_update' -d '{ "script": "ctx._source.service += new_date", "params": { "new_date": {"date": [ {"time": "time_new", "log": "log_new"} ]} } }'
```

В результате получаю:

```
{ service:{
           name: name,
           date: [{time:time, log: log}]
           date: [{time:time_new, log: log_new}]
          }
}
```

А хотелось бы:

```
{ service:{
           name: name,
           date: [{time:time, log: log}, {time:time_new, log: log_new}]
          }
}
```

Можно это сделать как-то более аккуратно, не создавать ещё один объект ?

2. Второй вопрос завязан на первом, как это можно выполнить через python
   ([API Documentation — Elasticsearch](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch)).
   Только начинаю разбираться с данной системой, сильно не пинайте:-)

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

1. Вам нужно использовать [scripting](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html). Вот пример из документации:

> We can also add a tag to the list of tags (note, if the tag exists, it will still add it, since its a list):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.tags += tag",
    "params" : {
        "tag" : "blue"
    }
}'
```

2. А в elasticsearch-py используйте [метод update](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update) с соотв значениями параметров.